# Can you describe the physics behind the Pen Spinning? (e.g: Thumbaround trick)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, momentum, torque

I met the Pen Spinning game and I liked it very much, it is a fun activity, but it can be addictive. I saw that it was a sport, but it was seriously dealt with. There are many super tricks, they are called power tricks. (e.g: Multiple bust) also combos can be made from the combination of tricks. I'm trying to learn tricks too. I tried for a long time, but I couldn't make much progress because I couldn't provide the necessary environment. (I didn't do a stylus mod). Now, while entertaining again, I started to wonder about the physics behind it. ( torque?, angular momentum?,)

**1)** Does torque really exist here? if so where?

**2)** why is it more efficient to push the middle finger from the pen's center of gravity?

**3)** At first hold, Why does she not hold the pen from the middle, but from the top? (Doesn't the pen have to rotate around the center?)

*** (maybe so that the center of gravity of the pen is directly above the thumb? to avoid being exposed to gravity.)

Can you explain the physics behind one of the most basic movements, Thumbaround?

Thumbaround trick (e.g Video):
[Thumbaround_trick Youtube Video Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loSqBQzOXVM)